# NextJS how to keep active class to parent navitem on dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app I have a Navbar with some navitems:

Navbar.tsx:

```
const Navbar = ({ navitems }) => {

  return (
     <div>
        {navitems?.map((navitem, idx) => (
          <NavItem key={idx} navitem={navitem} />
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

NavItem.tsx:

```
import Link from "next/link"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

const NavItem = ({navitem}) => {
   const router = useRouter()

   return (
     <div>
        <Link href={"/" + navitem.url.slug} 
              className={`${ router.query.slug === navitem?.url?.slug ? "active " : ""}`}>
          {navitem.title}
       </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavItem
```

So far so good. When I'm the route `/about` the menu item has the `active`-class.

How can I add the active class when I have dynamic routes like for example `/about/employees` - so that the Navitem "about" still has the active class?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you can check if url contains "about".  if it contains, keep the active class?

Comment: @DenizKaradağ thanks, but there must be a proper way to do this?!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I check for the current path by splitting the URL and comparing only the first part by  .split("/")[1] :

```
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";    

const pathname = usePathname();
const isCurrent = pathname.split("/")[1] === href.split("/")[1];
```